# flutter - bottom overflow appears and disappears when expanding expansion tile

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When expanding/shrinking expansion tile, the bottom overflow will appear and disappear without the screen having any size issue.

have a look at this short GIF:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xg7hH4zK_aIT04VjQPkRyJ789Lm728R4/view?usp=share_link

that is the code I am using:

```
      Card(
            elevation: 0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
            borderOnForeground: false,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            color: kBgLightColor,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0, right: 6.0, bottom: 12.0),
              child: ExpansionTile(
                onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isExpansionTileExpanded = value;
                  });
                },
                leading: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                backgroundColor: kBgLightColor,
                title: Text('Filters'),
                children: <Widget>[
                  CustomToggleButton(
                    toggleButtonOption: ToggleButtonOptions.teamOptions,
                    handler: toggleButtonHandler,
                    selectedItems: selectedTeamOption,
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.8,
                    items: teams,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems not to be the card but whatever is wrapping the card. I think what would work is wrap with `Column()` then use `SingleChildScrollView` and remember to disable the list scroll physics and use `SingleChildScrollView`'s scroll physics.

```
...
  SingleChildScrollView(
         physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
               children: [
                ...///card
               ]
..    )
```